# How to pass message.properties value to a String utility method in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

In my message.properties I have:

```
some.text=This text is for example
```

I would like to use one of Thymeleaf's String utility methods in my html for example:

```
<p th:text="${#strings.toUpperCase(#{some.text})}"></p>
```

But this line obviously doesn't work as I get an error. I don't seem to know how to pass **some.text** to a String utility method in Thymeleaf.

I couldn't find any similar examples in the documentation. 
Can someone with more experience explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the standard message (without the uppercase function wrapped around it) is already working OK for you.

Instead of using that standard way to show messages...

```
#{some.text}
```

... use this [alternative](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#messages-1) function-based syntax:

```
${#messages.msg('some.text')}
```

So now, when you place it inside the uppercase function, it will be this:

```
<p th:text="${#strings.toUpperCase(#messages.msg('some.text'))}"></p>
```

For some reason, Thymeleaf will not let you use a standard message expression as the parameter to one of its utility methods - not even with the `__${...}__` [preprocessor](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#preprocessing).

So instead, use a message *function* inside the uppercase function.