# Thymeleaf results in error when using variable inside an expression

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

For the provided string in my model, I want to print a "growing" list of substrings. For example, if the given string is `Wine`, the result should be:

```
W
Wi
Win
Wine
```

I've come up with the following construct:

```
<h1 th:with="len=${#strings.length(name)}" th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(1, ${len})}" th:text="${#strings.substring(name, 0, i)}"></h1>
```

but it doesn't work.

If I change `${#numbers.sequence(1, ${len})}` to `${#numbers.sequence(1, 4)}` it works. However, this way I'd need to manually change the code whenever my initial string's length changes.

I've tried with [`messages.msg()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61259996/how-to-pass-message-properties-value-to-a-string-utility-method-in-thymeleaf) alternative, but no luck either.

Error:

```
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/name-list.html]")
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#numbers.sequence(1, ${len})" (template: "name-list" - line 7, col 53)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `th:each` has a higher [attribute precedence](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence) than `th:with`.  Since `th:each` is evaluated first, the `len` variable is not available here.
2. In most cases, you should not/cannot nest `${...}` expressions.  If the len variable was available here, you should have used `len` instead of `${len}`.

.

```
<h1
  th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(1, #strings.length(name))}"
  th:text="${#strings.substring(name, 0, i)}" />
```